# I can't get my text to display under my carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn bootstrap 4 and I'm struggling to get my h2 text to display under the carousel.

```
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </div>

<!--------->
    <div class="container-fluid padding">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="display-4">
                    *text*
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

only relevant css

```
.carousel-inner> #imageSize{
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height to the `container-fluid` class

```
  .container-fluid{
     height: 10rem;
  }
```

View jsFiddle link to see the implementation https://jsfiddle.net/ykxt4qzd/